# Resizing all the elements inside a div using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, resize

I've used this -->

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('#recorder').css('-webkit-transform', 'scale(0.75)');
});
```

to resize all the elements(images, etc) to 75% of its orginal value. It worked fine in Chrome(Version 31.0.1650.63 m), but in firefox the div didn't seem to resize.

Is there any way i could make this work in more browsers? Thanks.

Comment: Not use `-webkit-` but just `transform`? jQuery do the compatibility for you.

Comment: I assume this is just a piece of a more complicated use-case? Because, they way you're doing it in your example code, you should just use CSS and no jQuery at all

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firefox isn't a webkit browsers, so no suprise there

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
     $('#recorder').css({
         '-webkit-transform' : 'scale(0.75)',
            '-moz-transform' : 'scale(0.75)',
             '-ms-transform' : 'scale(0.75)',
              '-o-transform' : 'scale(0.75)',
                 'transform' : 'scale(0.75)'
     });
});
```

It's worth noting that jQuery in many cases will do the prefixing for you, and transform should be one of the properties where that works as expected, so just using `transform` should be enough.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
     $('#recorder').css('transform', 'scale(0.75)');
});
```

Comment: As said in my comment, jQuery do the compatibility for you : http://jsfiddle.net/mzBte/. I'm using chrome and it add webkit before the transform. I don't know about older version.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon - Newer versions of jQuery adds the prefixes, but not for everything, but it works with transform, so I've added that to the answer as well.